# How to setup a ubuntu server that can receive iOS ASIHTTPRequests

Tags: iphone, ubuntu, asihttprequest

I have a ubuntu PC that I don't use for anything and I already know how to submit ASIHTTPRequests from an iPhone.

I would like to setup a very basic system where I can send an image from iPhone to my Ubuntu server and have my server just save that photo to a specific folder on my Ubuntu PC.

I have ZERO server knowledge but from what I have heard, this shouldn't be too terribly difficult to implement.  Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? (Easy for someone with no server knowledge?)

Answer (score 0):

Any web server will do. https://help.ubuntu.com/6.06/ubuntu/serverguide/C/httpd.html